# How to get Question/Answer body in the API response using filters?

Tags: support, api, questions, answers, filter

I am specifically looking to get the question/answer body back. Is it possible?

I am looking through the API documentation and I'm confused about how to make a call with filters.

Sample call I'm trying:
[/2.1/questions/1732348?site=stackoverflow](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/questions/1732348?site=stackoverflow)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most straightforward way to get the body is to use the named `withbody` filter, which you pass in as the value of the `filter` parameter ([example](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/questions/1234?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow&filter=withbody)). This will give you all of the default fields, along with the post body.

You can also create a [custom filter](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/filters) that passes back `question.body` and `answer.body` where appropriate along with your select choice of other fields, and use the ID of that filter instead ([example](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions#order=desc&sort=activity&filter=!9hnGssGO4&site=stackoverflow&run=true)).

Comment: Wow somehow I was only aware of customs filters and haven't used any other kind (-: