# How to get question body (markdown) in the API response using filters?

Tags: support, api, questions

Using `withbody` filter as suggested in this thread ([How to get Question/Answer body in the API response using filters?](https://stackapps.com/questions/3760/how-to-get-question-answer-body-in-the-api-response-using-filters)) returns body as HTML. How do I get the original markdown?

Answer (score 3):

The `body_markdown` field in the `question` (or `answer`) categories will give you the markdown.

So, `!9YdnSJ*_T` would be the filter to get a question with the markdown.

---

Demo: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18474564/bootstrap-3-navbar-with-logo?rq=1):

API URL: https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/18474564?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow&filter=!9YdnSJ*_T returns:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "tags": [
        "css",
        "twitter-bootstrap",
        "twitter-bootstrap-3",
        "navbar"
      ],
      "owner": {
        "reputation": 4298,
        "user_id": 182289,
        "user_type": "registered",
        "accept_rate": 74,
        "profile_image": "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/8a9e9df04ece9865fed808e9fdcdc41b?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG",
        "display_name": "stepanian",
        "link": "https://stackoverflow.com/users/182289/stepanian"
      },
      "is_answered": true,
      "view_count": 264551,
      "answer_count": 23,
      "score": 170,
      "last_activity_date": 1451887174,
      "creation_date": 1377634361,
      "last_edit_date": 1399668766,
      "question_id": 18474564,
      "body_markdown": "I want to use the Bootstrap 3 default navbar with an image logo instead of text branding. What&#39;s the proper way of doing this without causing any issues with different screen sizes? I assume this a common requirement, but I haven&#39;t yet seen a good code sample. A key requirement other than having acceptable display on all screen sizes is the menu collapsibility on smaller screens.\r\n\r\nI tried just putting an IMG tag inside the A tag that has the navbar-brand class, but that caused the menu not to function properly on my android phone. I also tried increasing the height of the navbar class, but that screwed things up even more.\r\n\r\nBy the way, my logo image is larger than the height of the navbar.",
      "link": "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18474564/bootstrap-3-navbar-with-logo",
      "title": "Bootstrap 3 Navbar with Logo"
    }
  ],
  "has_more": false,
  "quota_max": 10000,
  "quota_remaining": 9957
}
```

Note the `body_markdown`!

[image]

Comment: [Example of using the Filter edit tool](http://stackapps.com/a/4491/)